# Can't run nutch from a Tomcat webapp on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, nutch

I have a web app that spawns off a script that runs a Nutch crawl. It's all working really well, except now my client wants it running on a Windows PC.  The Windows PC she gave me is running Windows 7 Home Premium.

I've got nearly everything running, except when the crawl script - when it fires off nutch, nutch (which runs Hadoop, which for some bizarre reason does a `whoami`) fails because `whoami` returns "nt authority\system" instead of a single string.  The error:

> javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:
>   Login failed: Expect one token as the
>   result of whoami: nt authority\system

Is there some way to change the name that whoami returns in that case?

**Update**: Just to clarify, the exact same script runs fine when I run it from the command line.  The problem is that Tomcat runs as a service, so the script it spawns is running as this "nt authority\system" user, which is what is confusing hadoop because it evidently expects `whoami` to return a single word, not two words separated by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The problem is that Tomcat runs as a service, so the script it spawns is running as this "nt authority\system" user, which is what is confusing hadoop because it evidently expects whoami to return a single word, not two words separated by a space.*

Then change the account. *Start > Run > services.msc*, doubleclick the Tomcat service, open *Log On* tab and set the account there.

Comment: I did not know you could change that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I run Nutch on my Windows PC using Vista... almost daily, with cygwin installed have you tried ?

Comment: Yes, I have cygwin installed.  You're not answering the question - I'm trying to run it from within Tomcat, which is run as a service, so it doesn't run with the same userid as if you start it yourself.